# Why do we need an isolated USB to TTL converter cable for communication between the desktop CPU and the target?

Tags: embedded, meter

We can use non-isolated USB to TTL cable in between battery operated devices, ut when we are dealing with AC devices like communication between desktop CPU and electric meter (embedded MCU), we need an isolated USB to TTL converter.

Please let me know the logic behind this.

Comment: Why would it be a requirement to have isolated interface just because they are AC devices? You can use non-isolated interface between two computers and they are AC-powered. It may be a requirement of you electric meter and we don't know which electric meter it is, how it is made and why it requires an isolated interface, if it even requires an isolated interface at all. Please add in the details.

Comment: Gonna need a good reference saying you need isolation. IF you can find one, it may provide context relevant to its (possibly your) specific situation. There surely are jobs where the safety case requires isolation,, but as a blanket statement (with no qualification) it's just plain not true.

Answer (score 1):

**Two (2) significant advantages to Isolation** are commonly used for long cables and/or grid sensing meters.

1. **Common Mode Rejection Ratio (CMRR**) since the Zcm is just the pF coupling of an Opto or transformer.  Ethernet also includes CM chokes in the hybrid.
2. **HiPot Rating**: Vmax Insulation Breakdown protection

   - from exposure to transients. AC Power Meters normally have cones gapped to 6kV arc breakdown, but exposure above 3kV to 4kV typical isolation depends on duration of the arc and time to ionization causing breakdown.  This may be in the us range and depends on %RH and contamination in air.
   - devices downstream from the meter will have many uH of line inductance and Line filtering to slow down transients and thus reduce the HV pk amplitude so that PE grounded communication may be used between PC's.

- **Problems:**  You will find though that portable uC's with SMPS floating power supplies may cause USB communication errors with PE grounded towers but no errors with floating laptops.  So this proves the CMRR is a factor in signal integrity often caused by floating SMPS supplies creating significant CM noise may cause errors when communicating with PE grounded PC's.  ( Seen many times)

Comment: @kshitij singh I've had many a JTAG adaptor ruined due to not being isolated.  Those little transients can kill a cheaply designed circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> *Please let me know the logic behind this?*

We don't *need* an isolated data interface between AC powered devices but, it sure improves the comms reliability and significantly reduces the likelihood of multi-hundred-amp surge currents (due to indirect lightning strikes for example) passing between equipment and causing failure.

Ethernet uses 2 kV (or sometimes up to 6 kV) isolated magnetic data coupling for exactly the same reason so, why shouldn't any other data comms interface located in the same "surge" environment.